# How to get a value out of bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with BeautifulSoup for a web scraping project. The code is:

```
             var khtml='';

                khtml+='<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">' +
                    '<div class="panel panel-default" style=" background: #2b3648; color: white">' +
                    '<div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center">' +
                    '<div class="uk-card-header " style="color: #FF752C; font-size: 18px; max-width: 98%;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;">' +
                    'ALL / ON / ACTIVE' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="row">' +
                    // '<div class="col-xs-2">' +
                    // '<img src="/dashboard/images/telephone.svg" width="50" alt="" style="margin-top: 13px">' +
                    // '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12 tv-col" style=" max-width: 98%;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;">\n' +
                    '<b>\n' +
                    '<span style="font-size: 45px" > ' +  active + '/'+  on + '/' + total + '</span>\n' +
                    '<b>\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
```

and I want to retrieve value of "active,on,total" from this.

I tried using:

```
spans = soup.find_all('span')
for span in spans:
    print(span)
```

but this gives a None object . How to do I proceed?

Comment: What value? What is the expected output? You're placing those variables yourslf? Why?

Comment: Values ​​come from the server and are constantly changing.

Comment: Add a [mre]. Your question is unclear. Or are you trying to get the value inside the `uk-card-header` div?

Comment: This code is part of html page . values come from json data .  The code before these codes is as follows :  var active = data.active.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the values like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_code = '''
             var khtml='';

                khtml+='<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">' +
                    '<div class="panel panel-default" style=" background: #2b3648; color: white">' +
                    '<div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center">' +
                    '<div class="uk-card-header " style="color: #FF752C; font-size: 18px; max-width: 98%;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;">' +
                    'ALL / ON / ACTIVE' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="row">' +
                    // '<div class="col-xs-2">' +
                    // '<img src="/dashboard/images/telephone.svg" width="50" alt="" style="margin-top: 13px">' +
                    // '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12 tv-col" style=" max-width: 98%;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;">\n' +
                    '<b>\n' +
                    '<span style="font-size: 45px" > ' value1 '/' value2 '/' value3 '</span>\n' +
                    '<b>\n' +
                    '</div>\n' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')
span_element = soup.find('span', style="font-size: 45px")
values = span_element.get_text().strip().split('/')

value1, value2, value3 = values

print("Active:", value1)
print("On:", value2)
print("Total:", value3)
```